# Compiling Old Code in C# for SQL Assembly Errors

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, assemblies, compilation

I have old code that I just decompile (source was lost but we own it).

I'm now trying to recompile it but have these erros:

```
 Error  1   'System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlBoolean.operator true(System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlBoolean)': cannot explicitly call operator or accessor   C:\NCESTableGenerator\NCESTableGenerator\db\OutputTableDAO.cs   89  32  NCESTableGenerator
```

on the following piece of code:

```
 if (SqlBoolean.op_True(reader.GetSqlInt32(0) == 1))
```

and

```
 Error  3   Cannot convert type 'bool' to 'sbyte'   C:\NCESTableGenerator\NCESTableGenerator\Formatter.cs   172 30  NCESTableGenerator
```

on the following piece of code:

```
 public static string GetEstimateFloatStr(double data, int sn, int num, ref bool roundedZero, ref bool lowN)
    {
        if (sn <= 30)
        {
            sbyte num1 = (sbyte) lowN;
            lowN = true;
            return "‡";
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Decompiling will not always give you back code that can just be recompiled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first line I think it's safe to rewrite it as

```
if (reader.GetSqlInt32(0) == 1)
```

and the 2nd one the troublesome line (looks like it can be removed because of the return) but if you cant remove it change it to

```
Int16 num1 = (Int16)lowN;
```

or

```
char num1 = (char)lowN;
```

Since Sbyte is not CLS-Compliant as listed by MSDN.

Comment: yeah i have no idea why there is a new var created there then a return, i can't think of any reason what that line would accomplish

Comment: Yeah when you decompile code often you see really odd things but it's hard to tell if it's there for a reason or just a bug/error in the decompiler.